# Vertically align content inside a grid of div tags

Tags: html, css, grid, alignment

Im making a grid with div tags to put different types of content in there like pictures, text, headings, buttons etc. I tried atleast 3 different ways to make a grid and now i finally found the best way for me.
The grid now is looking good and works perfect, however i have 1 problem, i cannot align 1 text to the bottom.

Now for my question:

How do i align the call-to-action text at the bottom of the div while keeping the rest of the content at the top. I would like to be able to do this by just adding some rules instead of taking a whole different approach by building the grid.

The part that should be aligned at the bottom is called "Bekijk dit artikel".

All suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: - JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Lookinggoodtoday/AL6Qn/1/

Comment: JSFIDDLE update: http://jsfiddle.net/Lookinggoodtoday/AL6Qn/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use positioning here.

```
.blok3-a {position: relative;}
.text-container-link {position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AL6Qn/2/

If you don´t  know height of content above, there is no other way using your HTML and align text only with CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Panther. It did the trick, all call-to-actions are now aligned at the bottom. Except for 1 block!

http://jsfiddle.net/Lookinggoodtoday/AL6Qn/5/

Any suggestions why this 1 block on the left does'nt show the text at the bottom like the other divs now do?

Many thanks.

Comment: If you mean `blok2-a` with text `blok 1 - b`, there is set `height: 330px`, but real height is lower.

Answer (score 1):

Check out CSS Position properties
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp
You should be able to provide your text with an absolute position.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did read about the positions and tried several different ways described in other topics. Sometimes i got the vertical alignment working but then the grid itself became messed up. Hard to get it all working!